# Python gets an error in ODE function: Cannot cast array data from dtype('complex128') to dtype('float64')

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, ode

I wrote the following code, similar to myriad of codes that I have written. This one sent an error which I could not manage to solve it. Any help please?

```
def HUB(H,z,rc,beta,b,w,c,Om):
    H1 = ((1/H**2)*(3*b-3+beta)*Om*(1/(z+1))**(3*b-3+beta))-0.33*beta**3*w*(1/(z+1))**(-2*beta)
    H2 = (2*(1-beta-0.166*(beta**2*w*(1/(z+1))**(-2*beta))-2*c**2*(1-(1/(2*rc*H)))))
    hubble = -(H/(1+z))*(H1/H2)
    return hubble

def solution(z1,z,H0,rc,beta,b,w,c,Om):
    U = odeint(HUB,H0,[z1,z], args=(rc,beta,b,w,c,Om)) [-1]                 
    return U

for z in np.arange(-1,2.05,0.05):
    q=solution(0,z,69.9,0.08,0.498,0.035,20,0.69,0.235)[-1]
    print(z,q)
```

...
the error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\esadr21\Desktop\INHDEFC\ANHDEIFC\m1\1st Model .py", line      24, in <module>
    q=solution(0,z,69.9,0.08,0.498,0.035,20,0.69,0.235)[-1]
  File "C:\Users\esadr21\Desktop\INHDEFC\ANHDEIFC\m1\1st Model .py", line 20, in solution
    U = odeint(HUB,H0,[z1,z], args=(rc,beta,b,w,c,Om)) [-1]
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\odepack.py", line 215, in odeint
    ixpr, mxstep, mxhnil, mxordn, mxords)
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('complex128') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'
```

thank you for your hlp.

Answer (score 0):

There is likely a power of a negative number somewhere in your expression. For `(-1)**(1/2)` for instance, Python returns `6.123233995736766e-17+1j` that is a complex number. The routines for ODES here only work for real-valued quantities.

I changed two things to your code.

1. I give values for z above -1
2. I change the "time" argument of odeint to a series of points instead of just two.

   ```
   def HUB(H,z,rc,beta,b,w,c,Om):
       H1 = ((1/H**2)*(3*b-3+beta)*Om*(1/(z+1))**(3*b-3+beta))-0.33*beta**3*w*(1/(z+1))**(-2*beta)
       H2 = (2*(1-beta-0.166*(beta**2*w*(1/(z+1))**(-2*beta))-2*c**2*(1-(1/(2*rc*H)))))
       hubble = -(H/(1+z))*(H1/H2)
       return hubble

   def solution(z1,z,H0,rc,beta,b,w,c,Om):
       U = odeint(HUB,H0,np.linspace(z1,z,3), args=(rc,beta,b,w,c,Om))[-1]
       return U

   for z in [-0.5, 1., 2.]:
       q=solution(0,z,69.9,0.08,0.498,0.035,20,0.69,0.235)[-1]
       print(z,q)
   ```

Comment: Two problems appear: 1. Your equation has a singularity at z=-1 and possible negative values in exponents resulting in complex results. 2. The way to pass a time range to odeint is to pass a series of points along which the results will be given. I'll update the answer in a minute.